# Return the context and not just the matching lines

Tags: regex, awk, ripgrep

I tried to find this string in the verse.

```
.* चैव यत् .*
```

It returned 2 lines:

```
अभिसन्धाय तु फलं दम्भार्थमपि चैव यत् ।

सत्कारमानपूजार्थं तपो दम्भेन चैव यत् ।
```

But I need to return the complete paragraph.
In this context it is the text between ॥

```
अभिसन्धाय तु फलं दम्भार्थमपि चैव यत् ।
इज्यते भरतश्रेष्ठ तं यज्ञं विद्धि राजसम् ॥ 17.12॥

सत्कारमानपूजार्थं तपो दम्भेन चैव यत् ।
क्रियते तदिह प्रोक्तं राजसं चलमध्रुवम् ॥ 17.18॥
```

The sample text:

```
दृष्ट्वा तु पाण्डवानीकं व्यूढं दुर्योधनस्तदा ।
आचार्यमुपसङ्गम्य राजा वचनमब्रवीत् ॥ १-२॥

पश्यैतां पाण्डुपुत्राणामाचार्य महतीं चमूम् ।
व्यूढां द्रुपदपुत्रेण तव शिष्येण धीमता ॥ १-३॥

अन्ये च बहवः शूरा मदर्थे त्यक्तजीविताः ।
नानाशस्त्रप्रहरणाः सर्वे युद्धविशारदाः ॥ १-९॥

अपर्याप्तं तदस्माकं बलं भीष्माभिरक्षितम् ।
पर्याप्तं त्विदमेतेषां बलं भीमाभिरक्षितम् ॥ १-१०॥


अभिसन्धाय तु फलं दम्भार्थमपि चैव यत् ।
इज्यते भरतश्रेष्ठ तं यज्ञं विद्धि राजसम् ॥ 17.12॥

अयनेषु च सर्वेषु यथाभागमवस्थिताः ।
भीष्ममेवाभिरक्षन्तु भवन्तः सर्व एव हि ॥ १-११॥

सत्कारमानपूजार्थं तपो दम्भेन चैव यत् ।
क्रियते तदिह प्रोक्तं राजसं चलमध्रुवम् ॥ 17.18॥
```

---

Update:

If I have plain text file with no line breaks like this...

```
दृष्ट्वा तु पाण्डवानीकं व्यूढं दुर्योधनस्तदा । आचार्यमुपसङ्गम्य राजा वचनमब्रवीत् ॥ १-२॥ पश्यैतां पाण्डुपुत्राणामाचार्य महतीं चमूम् । व्यूढां द्रुपदपुत्रेण तव शिष्येण धीमता ॥ १-३॥ अन्ये च बहवः शूरा मदर्थे त्यक्तजीविताः । नानाशस्त्रप्रहरणाः सर्वे युद्धविशारदाः ॥ १-९॥ अपर्याप्तं तदस्माकं बलं भीष्माभिरक्षितम् । पर्याप्तं त्विदमेतेषां बलं भीमाभिरक्षितम् ॥ १-१०॥ अभिसन्धाय तु फलं दम्भार्थमपि चैव यत् । इज्यते भरतश्रेष्ठ तं यज्ञं विद्धि राजसम् ॥ 17.12॥ अयनेषु च सर्वेषु यथाभागमवस्थिताः । भीष्ममेवाभिरक्षन्तु भवन्तः सर्व एव हि ॥ १-११॥ सत्कारमानपूजार्थं तपो दम्भेन चैव यत् । क्रियते तदिह प्रोक्तं राजसं चलमध्रुवम् ॥ 17.18॥
```

Is it possible to extract relevant verses (17.12 and 17.18)?

```
अभिसन्धाय तु फलं दम्भार्थमपि चैव यत् । इज्यते भरतश्रेष्ठ तं यज्ञं विद्धि राजसम् ॥ 17.12॥ सत्कारमानपूजार्थं तपो दम्भेन चैव यत् । क्रियते तदिह प्रोक्तं राजसं चलमध्रुवम् ॥ 17.18॥
```

Comment: Is the `॥` always an important marker for the end of the paragraph? Or do you want to match all following lines that start with a non whitespace character like `.* चैव यत् .*(?:\n\S.*)*` https://regex101.com/r/Rdnfae/1

Comment: This is correct. Can you post it as answer? and explain a little :)

Comment: If in case the paragraph always ends with  double dash ॥ then what will be the query? In order to save space, I want to remove all line breaks.

Comment: If there should be at least 2 lines, you might write it like this `.* चैव यत् .*(?:\n(?!.*॥$)\S.*)*\n\S.*॥$` https://regex101.com/r/Rdnfae/2 Or if `॥` can also be just by it self on a single line ॥ https://regex101.com/r/Rdnfae/3

Comment: No. This is not correct. question updated.

Comment: Are you using ripgrep with pcre2? Perhaps like this https://regex101.com/r/5dZE9a/1

Comment: awesome. Thank you. I do not think explanation is needed. :)

Comment: Regarding "Update: ... Is it possible" - yes, it's trivial but don't ask 2 questions in 1, ask 1 clear question at a time with it's own [mcve].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using any awk that can handle multi-byte characters, e.g. GNU awk, in [paragraph mode](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Multiple-Line):

```
$ awk -v RS= -v ORS='\n\n' '/ चैव यत् /' file
अभिसन्धाय तु फलं दम्भार्थमपि चैव यत् ।
इज्यते भरतश्रेष्ठ तं यज्ञं विद्धि राजसम् ॥ 17.12॥

सत्कारमानपूजार्थं तपो दम्भेन चैव यत् ।
क्रियते तदिह प्रोक्तं राजसं चलमध्रुवम् ॥ 17.18॥
```

Answer (score 0):

Using ripgrep with pcre2 enabled and asserting a whitespace boundary to the right with `(?!\S)`

```
(?<=॥ |^)(?:(?!\d[.-]\d+॥).)*?चैव यत्(?:(?!\d[.-]\d+॥).)*\d[.-]\d+॥(?!\S)
```

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Y6OFGQ/1).

---

Or a shortened variation using `(?1)` repeating the expression defined in the first capture group and omitting the whitespace boundary to the right is that is unnecessary:

```
(?<=॥ |^)((?!\d[.-]\d+॥).)*?चैव यत्(?1)*\d[.-]\d+॥
```

The pattern matches:

- `(?<=॥ |^)` Positive lookbehind, assert either ॥ or the start of the string to the left
- `(` Capture **group 1**

  - `(?!\d[.-]\d+॥).` [Tempered greedy token](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30900794/tempered-greedy-token-what-is-different-about-placing-the-dot-before-the-negat), match any character if not directly followed by a digit, then either `.` or `-` and the 1+ digits followed by ॥
- `)*?` Close group 1 and optionally repeat it, as few as possible times
- `चैव यत्` Match literally
- `(?1)*` Optionally repeat the expression defined in the first capture group
- `\d[.-]\d+॥ Match a digit, either` .`or`-` 1+ digits and ॥

See another [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Kk9YK8/1).

Answer (score 0):

Another brain-bender to get the paragraph containing a special string.

```
(?m)^\s*\K(?:^.*\S.*\r?\n)*?^.*[ ]चैव[ ]यत्[ ].*(?:\r?\n^.*\S.*)*
```

https://regex101.com/r/eLNpw6/1

Overview

```
(?m)
^ \s* 
\K 
(?: ^ .* \S .* \r? \n )*?
^ .* [ ] चैव [ ] यत् [ ] .* 
(?: \r? \n ^ .* \S .* )*
```